# plt.quiver() plotting dots instead of vectors in some places

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently analyzing some data by creating a vector plot. All the vectors have length 1 unit. Most show up fine, but certain vectors such as:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.axes(xlim=(-24, 24), ylim=(0, 150))
plt.quiver([-19.1038], [96.5851], [-19.1001+19.1038], [97.5832-96.5851],angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1, headwidth=1, headlength=10, minshaft=5)
plt.show()
```

show up as a point. (Please note that I am not drawing my vectors individually like this; I only drew this particular one to try to debug my code.) This appears to only be occurring for nearly vertical vectors. I've also noticed that this issue is resolved if I "zoom in" on the vector (i.e. change the axis scaling). However, I cannot do that as many other vectors in my plot will be outside of the domain/range. Is there another way to fix this?

The problem is demonstrated in the below figure:

[image: demonstration of the problem: only vertical arrows are rendered as dots]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two components to your problem, and both have to do with how you chose to represent your data.

The default behaviour of `quiver` is to auto-scale your vectors to a reasonable size for a pretty result. [The documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver) says as much:

> The default settings auto-scales the length of the arrows to a reasonable size. To change this behavior see the `scale` and `scale_units` kwargs.

And then

> scale_units : [ ‘width’ | ‘height’ | ‘dots’ | ‘inches’ | ‘x’ | ‘y’ | ‘xy’ ], None, optional
>
> [...]
>
> If scale_units is ‘x’ then the vector will be 0.5 x-axis units. To plot vectors in the x-y plane, with u and v having the same units as x and y, use angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1.

So in your case, you're telling `quiver` to plot the arrow in `xy` data units. Since your arrow is of unit length, it is drawn as a 1-length arrow. Your data limits, on the other hand, are huge: 40 units wide, 150 units tall. On this scale a length-1 arrow is just too small, and matplotlib decides to truncate the arrow and plot a dot instead.

If you zoom in, as you said yourself, the arrow appears. If we remove the parameters that turn your arrow into a toothpick, it turns out that the arrow you plot is perfectly fine if you look close enough (not the axes):

[image: result: single arrow zoomed in]

Now, the question is why this behaviour depends on the orientation of your vectors. The reason for this behaviour is that the x and y limits are different in your plot, so a unit-length horizontal line and a unit-length vertical line contain a different number of pixels (since your data is scaled in *xy* units). This implies that while horizontal arrows are long enough to be represented accurately, vertical ones become so short that matplotlib decides to truncate them to dots, which shouldn't be *too* obvious with the default arrow format, but it is pretty bad with your custom arrows. Your use case is such that the rendering cut-off used by matplotlib happens to fall between the length of your horizontal vectors and the length of your vertical ones.

You have two straightforward choices. One is to increase the scaling for your arrows to the point where every orientation is represented accurately. This would probably be the solution to Y in a small XY problem here. What you should *really* do, is represent your data accurately. Since you're plotting your vector field in *xy* data units, you presumably want your `x` and `y` axes to have equal sizes, and you want your arrows to have visually unit length (i.e. a length that's independent from their orientation).

So I suggest that you force your plot to have equal units on both axes, at the cost of ending up with a rectangular figure:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis('scaled') # <-- key addition
ax.axis([-24, 24, 0, 150])
ax.quiver([-19.1038], [96.5851], [-19.1001+19.1038], [97.5832-96.5851],
          angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1, headwidth=1,
          headlength=10, minshaft=5)
plt.show()
```

[image: result with equal axes scaling]

Trust me: there's a tiny arrow in there. The main point is that this way either all of your vectors will be dots (if you're zoomed out too much), or neither of them will. Then you have a sane situation, and can choose the overall scaling of your vectors accordingly.

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're saying correctly, you're saying that it isn't drawing a point and it just looks like a point from far away. However, I'm fairly certain this isn't the case. Attached is a figure of many vectors all of length 1 unit with the axis scaling I was using before. However, the ones closer to vertical are dots and the others are vectors. ( I accidentally posted this before learning how to add images so please bear with me)

Comment: @JustinRoberts it's OK, you can't directly insert pictures into comments. Open the editor for your question, insert the image, copy the link, discard your edit, and post the image link here instead. And yes, the arrow probably becomes a small dot, but that's because matplotlib probably doesn't do arbitrary-precision arithmetic under the hood, and rounds values to some small precision before plotting.

Comment: Evidently I cannot edit my comment after 5 minutes. A link is attached to this post with an image of the figure I previously referenced. My apologies if there is a standard for submitting images that I have missed.
https://imgur.com/a/Nzcsh
It's somewhat "zoomed out" but you can see from that image that some vectors appear as actual vectors while others appear as larger "dots". Thank you by the way for the help. I've been stumped by this for quite awhile.

Comment: @JustinRoberts I think you should add your figure to your question, since this clearly describes your issue (which your current question doesn't, since it contains only a single vector). Edit: are you positive that all the vectors are of unit length?

Comment: Although for some reason they appear to be slightly different length in the figure, I am fairly certain that they are the same length as I have printed the lists I am using for the coordinates to the console to check.

Comment: I just iterated through all of my data and the maximum deviation in length is about 2.3%. However, it is just from a small, nonzero z-component which i neglected for purposes of simplicity.

Comment: It worked! Thank you again for taking the time to help me with this. I'm not sure I would have ever guessed to do that.

Comment: @JustinRoberts I'm glad it did:) Since this is your first question on the site: in case you find the answer satisfactory to your question, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). This will indicate that the question no longer needs an answer, and it will also give some reputation to the both of us.